# Image toggling working only for one id on live website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a limited js/jquery knowledge and I'm having a hard time figuring out why I am not able to make the following setup work on a live website; the second image doesn't toggle there.

It does work on Fiddle tho: https://jsfiddle.net/05vkw2mj/2/

#HTML

```
<div id="rodrigo">
RODRIGO

<img src="https://ywamsantiago.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/MG_1218-Rodrigo-Oliveira-copy-web-ready-500x500.jpg" id="rodrigo-img"/></div>

<div id="bob">
BOB

<img src="https://ywamsantiago.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/MG_1218-Rodrigo-Oliveira-copy-web-ready-500x500.jpg" id="bob-img"/></div>
```

#JQUERY

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rodrigo").hover(function() {
      $("#rodrigo-img").toggle();
    });

    $("#bob").hover(function() {
      $("#bob-img").toggle();
    })
  });
```

#CSS

```
body {
  padding-top:400px;
}
#rodrigo {
  position: relative;
}
#rodrigo-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left:0;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#bob {
  position: relative;
}
#bob-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left:0;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: if you can't demonstrate code that doesn't work, then how can we answer? perhaps your real code has a typo

Comment: @Bravo I was led to believe the reason it's not working live is a mistake in my code. Maybe the something with the divs or classes.

Comment: but the code you posted works on jsfiddle (and here in a snippet) ... have you checked the browser console for errors where it doesn't work?

Comment: I did, nothing pops up except for a message about an update on JQMigrate.

Comment: well, it's a mystery unless you can post code that actually demonstrates your issue - the problem with jquery is ... a typo in a selector won't show up as an error .... so, if you have `$("#Bob").hover(function() {` instead of `$("#bob").hover(function() {` ... that's perfectly fine for jquery, even though there's no element with `id="Bob"` - that's one of my (many) pet hates for jquery

Comment: @Bravo it was exactly that. Man, jquery is such a …. but thanks a lot.

Comment: what you're looking for is "too forgiving" (at times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be a little easier to follow.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".links").hover(function(e) {
    $($(e.target).data().img).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.links {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1020/300" id="rodrigo-img" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/300" id="bob-img" />
</div>
<div id="rodrigo" class="links" data-img="#rodrigo-img">
  RODRIGO
</div>
<div id="bob" class="links" data-img="#bob-img">
  BOB
</div>
```

Comment: It was not a direct fix to the problem, but the better formatting and structure helped me spot the problem. I'm accepting it as a solution for the time you put here.